# Pass dynamic value in URL with CakePHP

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

I have the following method that performs an Ajax request passing some dynamic value obtained from a select input.

It works fine, but the dynamic value is passed as parameter in the URL, something like *`states/listCities/?big_string_of_serialized_parameter`* .

```
$this->Js->event(
    'change', 
    $this->Js->request(
        array( #url
            'controller' => 'states', 
            'action' => 'listCities'),
        array( # ajax options that generates the serialized parameter
           'update' => '#DealerCityId', 
           'data' => '$("#DealerStateId").serialize()',
           'dataExpression' => true
        )
    )
);
```

I'm trying to do this in a more friendly URL way, something like *`states/listCities/2`*.

It's possible in CakePHP to generate a friendly URL like this with dynamic value from a input or is only possible passing the dynamic values as parameters?

Comment: I dont know cakePHP but basically you are looking more for a server rewriting url rule than a php script

Comment: @roasted, I know how to do this "by my hands", but in this question, I'm interested in the way that CakePHP does.

Comment: Why are you trying to beautify url accessed by ajax only? It's pointless. Users are not going to see the url so why add extra cruft to your code?

Comment: @ADmad First, only by curiosity, if it is possible to do this or not. Second, I think that processing a parameter that comes in a friendly URL produces a cleaner code that ones that comes as parameter (at least in CakePHP). Third, MAYBE one day there will be a project where some URL can be acessed by Ajax or a "normal way". It works fine now, but I'm only trying to improve the things.

Comment: There is nothing unclean about passing params as querystring aka GET. Readup about routing on the CakePHP manual if you want fancy urls. Cake also has the "named params" features but it's just like a proprietary version of querystring.

Also I would advice you to ditch the JsHelper and write jquery code yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it's not possible. You could pass an ID as third parameter in the URL array, but as the ID is not known at template generation time, it's not applicable in this situation. If you want to use `JsHelper`, you'll have to stick with the JavaScript code generation it provides.

As an alternative, you could write your own Helper: Derive it from `JsHelper` and override the `request()` method to suit your needs. You can probably take the source code of the original source code to get a head start and only modify the way the `data` parameter is used in code generation.